# Is it possible to make CMake print one variable at the end from command line?

Tags: cmake, trace

### Scenario

I'm in the process of debugging a CMake script.
In order to produce usable output for me to inspect, I use the following invocation:

```bash
cmake -S . -B build -DENABLE_MODULE_A=OFF -DENABLE_MODULE_B=OFF -DENABLE_MODULE_C=OFF --trace-source=CMakeLists.txt --trace-expand |& grep VARIABLE_IM_INTERESTED_IN > build/testout.utf8
```

### Problem

This approach is sub-par, because I'm really only interested in one variable that is expanded in the CMake script in question. `grep`-ing for that after running it in trace-mode seems to be quite cumbersome, especially since the variable gets expanded multiple times, however I'm interested only in the last, full expansion of said variable.

### Desired result

Ideally, there is a command line option for CMake, to print/expand only *the one* variable I'm interested in. I can filter for the last occurrence of that variable with external tools (for instance `tail`), but grepping the entire trace output for just one file, seems excessive. In essence I'm looking for a command line option to inspect an arbitrary variable, instead of tracing the entirety of the CMake script.

It is however, not an option to change the `CMakeFiles.txt` such that this one variable is printed. That is for external reasons, of which I have no control of.

Comment: I assume you're not looking for the value of a ***cache*** variable? Otherwise `cmake -N -LAH build_dir | grep ...` would do the trick or simply `grep ... build_dir/CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: @fabian unfortunatelly, no. In fact I have to wipe the cache before each run to inspect those variables, as it is bound to file changes.

Answer (score 3):

Use `variable_watch` and `CMAKE_PROJECT_INCLUDE_BEFORE` as a debugging tool. Create a file called `watch_var.cmake` with the following contents:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)

variable_watch("${watch_var}")
```

Now here's an example project:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(example)

set(VARIABLE_IM_INTERESTED_IN foo)
string(APPEND VARIABLE_IM_INTERESTED_IN " bar")
```

At the command line:

```
$ cmake -G Ninja -S . -B build -DCMAKE_PROJECT_INCLUDE_BEFORE=$PWD/watch_var.cmake -Dwatch_var=VARIABLE_IM_INTERESTED_IN
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 10.2.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.2.1
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Debug Log at CMakeLists.txt:4 (set):
  Variable "VARIABLE_IM_INTERESTED_IN" was accessed using MODIFIED_ACCESS
  with value "foo".


CMake Debug Log at CMakeLists.txt:5 (string):
  Variable "VARIABLE_IM_INTERESTED_IN" was accessed using READ_ACCESS with
  value "foo".


CMake Debug Log at CMakeLists.txt:5 (string):
  Variable "VARIABLE_IM_INTERESTED_IN" was accessed using MODIFIED_ACCESS
  with value "foo bar".


-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/reinking/test2/build
```

Docs: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/variable_watch.html